# How can I keep a box at the edge of a browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

I want to make a tooltip div that appears next to and top-aligned to a certain input element when that element receives focus:

```
                bla bla blah
 ____________    ___________________
| this       |  [_button____clicked_]
| appears    |
| on side    |  body content dafjsd fdjskf sdf
|____________|  content djsfs df skfjs daskf kdf s
                text texty djkf jsk fdjfs
                texty hehe blabla ajdfskfsd
```

I can do this with absolute positioning. But I don't want all of the tooltip to be visible without scrolling, so if the input box happens to be at the bottom of the window, the tooltip should adjust to stay in view:

```
                content djsfs df skfjs daskf kdf s
                text texty djkf jsk fdjfs
                texty hehe blabla ajdfskfsd
 ____________   bla bla blah
| this       |   ___________________
| appears    |  [_button____clicked_]
| on side    |
|____________|  edge of broswer window  vvv
------------------------------------------------------------
```

That is, the tooltip should stick as close as possible to its proper position while staying within the window as the user scrolls up and down.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to your dilemma if you read the code of this fairly simple javascript rooted tooltip script: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm.

It detects the edges of the browser window and displays in a different position based on that input very smoothly. Test out the tooltip demos near the top of the page and you'll see what I mean.

But to directly answer your question - the best way would be to use javascript, first to check what browser is being used, and then use the appropriate screen width calculations to display the tooltip based on the width, height, and current 'location' of the browser window. Examples of this conditional browser logic and screen width calculation can be found in the code linked above :)

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

After some thought, I figured I would just include the JS aspect of the code linked to above in case the link were to one day fail, just for reference. It is a little cryptic but it nonetheless is a script that deals with tooltip positioning based on the browser window:

```
var offsetxpoint=-60 //Customize x offset of tooltip
var offsetypoint=20 //Customize y offset of tooltip
var ie=document.all
var ns6=document.getElementById && !document.all
var enabletip=false
if (ie||ns6)
var tipobj=document.all? document.all["dhtmltooltip"] : document.getElementById? document.getElementById("dhtmltooltip") : ""

function ietruebody(){
return (document.compatMode && document.compatMode!="BackCompat")? document.documentElement : document.body
}

function ddrivetip(thetext, thecolor, thewidth){
if (ns6||ie){
if (typeof thewidth!="undefined") tipobj.style.width=thewidth+"px"
if (typeof thecolor!="undefined" && thecolor!="") tipobj.style.backgroundColor=thecolor
tipobj.innerHTML=thetext
enabletip=true
return false
}
}

function positiontip(e){
if (enabletip){
var curX=(ns6)?e.pageX : event.clientX+ietruebody().scrollLeft;
var curY=(ns6)?e.pageY : event.clientY+ietruebody().scrollTop;
//Find out how close the mouse is to the corner of the window
var rightedge=ie&&!window.opera? ietruebody().clientWidth-event.clientX-offsetxpoint : window.innerWidth-e.clientX-offsetxpoint-20
var bottomedge=ie&&!window.opera? ietruebody().clientHeight-event.clientY-offsetypoint : window.innerHeight-e.clientY-offsetypoint-20

var leftedge=(offsetxpoint<0)? offsetxpoint*(-1) : -1000

//if the horizontal distance isn't enough to accomodate the width of the context menu
if (rightedge<tipobj.offsetWidth)
//move the horizontal position of the menu to the left by it's width
tipobj.style.left=ie? ietruebody().scrollLeft+event.clientX-tipobj.offsetWidth+"px" : window.pageXOffset+e.clientX-tipobj.offsetWidth+"px"
else if (curX<leftedge)
tipobj.style.left="5px"
else
//position the horizontal position of the menu where the mouse is positioned
tipobj.style.left=curX+offsetxpoint+"px"

//same concept with the vertical position
if (bottomedge<tipobj.offsetHeight)
tipobj.style.top=ie? ietruebody().scrollTop+event.clientY-tipobj.offsetHeight-offsetypoint+"px" : window.pageYOffset+e.clientY-tipobj.offsetHeight-offsetypoint+"px"
else
tipobj.style.top=curY+offsetypoint+"px"
tipobj.style.visibility="visible"
}
}

function hideddrivetip(){
if (ns6||ie){
enabletip=false
tipobj.style.visibility="hidden"
tipobj.style.left="-1000px"
tipobj.style.backgroundColor=''
tipobj.style.width=''
}
}

document.onmousemove=positiontip
```